# Why is IEnumerable<object> not null after LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List which holds > 10.000 items. I am doing a LINQ query on this

```
IEnumerable<Term> terms = from t in regionCollection
                           where t.Name == strRegion
                           select t;

if (terms != null)
{
    m.RegId = Convert.ToInt32(terms.FirstOrDefault().CustomProperties["dbId"]);
}
```

If (terms !=null) is always **not null**! I have a feeling that the query is executed only if i try to access the single object inside the IEnumarable. Is this correct and if yes how can i check if my IEnumarable is not null?

Comment: Yes, such `from` queries are lazily evaluated.

Comment: Terms will always be not null, but it can be empty, so you could do: if (terms.Any())

Comment: @FrederikGheysels, in regards to the answer that was removed... terms is assigned the return of Select; the underline collection is `List`, the `IEnumerable<T>.Select` in question is `System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<T, T>((List<T> as IEnumerable<T>), (item) => item)` you're saying this is deferred lazy?

Comment: @FrederikGheysels, I asked, because it took me a bit to find it.. it appears it is indeed yielding: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L50 .. btw, I'm suprised it is not using IEnumerator<T> within `SelectIterator`..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable `term` will always have a value, it will never be null, because if query returns no results then `terms` will be empty enumerable. In your case you can update the code like this:

```
// Get first item of query or default value
var firstTerm = terms.FirstOrDefault();
// If there were no items, then firstTerm is null
if (firstTerm != null)
{
    // This code block is only executed if the query had at least 1 item in results
    m.RegId = Convert.ToInt32(firstTerm.CustomProperties["dbId"]);
}
```

Comment: That was the missing link. Thank you. I will mark it as answwer in 7 minutes :)

Comment: `var firstTerm = regionCollection.FirstOrDefault((t) => t.Name == strRegion);`